# App Store Connect - Can't see my app rejection issues in TestFlight

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, testflight

I uploaded a build of my app to App Store Connect and submitted it to a group of external testers in TestFlight (without submitting to App Store).

The build status goes from "waiting for review" to "rejected":

[image]

The problem is that I didn't received the "Unresolved issues" or reviews. I searched in every page and can't find it.

How can I see "Unresolved issues" of a build in TestFlight only?

Comment: I also have the same issue. My TestFlight app has been rejected and I can't find the reason why

Answer (score 11):

Okay so this is how I found the resolution centre:

1. Login to App Store Connect
2. Select my apps
3. Select the app with the issue
4. In the AppStore tab, look on the left under General you will find Version History, click on it.
5. On the right, you should see the Resolution Centre there as depicted below

[image]

Comment: That is so bad UX its baffling! Why not have the link on the "rejected" status text?
It's clear this App Store Connect site never went under any QA process. It has so many problems that one blog post would not be able to cover them. Maybe I'll make a series then.

Comment: Seems this is not working anymore. Resolution Centre button not appearing here anymore for TestFlight rejection. At least, not helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Resolution Center via direct link, just paste your app id:

[https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apps/[your_app_id]/appstore/platform/ios/resolutioncenter](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apps/%5Byour_app_id%5D/appstore/platform/ios/resolutioncenter)

Answer (score 0):

as @nivla360 answer above on 2020, i got new update for 2022.

After selected your app in the app store connect,in the app store tab

- look at the left side  on **General** then click on 'App Review'.
- you should find the button 'resolve' on the right side of your app version activity.
  [image: just like this one]